# Variadic __is_trivially_constructible built-in predicate

Tags: c++, clang, type-traits

[Documentation of clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checks-for-type-trait-primitives) WRT built-in type traits says:

- > __is_trivially_constructible(type, argtypes...): Determines whether a value of type type can be direct-initialized with arguments of types argtypes... such that no non-trivial functions are called as part of that initialization. This trait is required to implement the C++11 standard library.

What is the example of the *C++* type, which can be non-unary direct-initialized? I.e. (e.g. for arity 2) expression `T(x, y)` is well-formed and trivial simultaneously?

Comment: I am still trying to understand the idea . You can find a little bit more information at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible.

Comment: @RSahu Maybe `struct S { constexpr S(char c, int j) : ch(c), i(j) { ; } char c; int i; };` during direct-initialization `S('a', 0)` perform no non-trivial operations during construction? But assertion fails for `S`. Maybe sometimes fully member-initializer-list constructed classes of trivially constructible elements also can be trivially constructible?

Comment: From the linked page: *but the variable definition does not call any operation that is not trivial.*  The trait depends not only `type` but also `argtypes`. It will be useful if you can post the code that you tried and results you got.

Comment: @RSahu comment above has such code, but as I noted - this attempt failed. I request an example.